# How can one get readable data(JSON, XML format or any other format) from Medical Equipments like Cardiac or heart monitors, Pulse oximeter?

Tags: interaction, medical

I am new to this domain and i want to know that how can one interact with medical equipments to get readable data to get saved into the SQL Database? So, that one can maintain the data on Server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to write code that understands the format each device uses (often binary).  You can convert it to a readable format in your code, but there's no guarantee that any format coming from the device will be human-readable.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are looking for this API.
It is provided by [FDA](http://www.fda.gov).

[openFDA Unique Device Identifier](https://open.fda.gov/device/udi/)

> The unique device identification system was established to identify devices through distribution and use. Device labelers are required to include a unique device identifier (UDI) on device labels and packages. The Global Unique Device Identification Database (GUDID) contains key device identification information submitted to the FDA.

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on the equipment. It's very likely you will need a separate module to retrieve data from the device and converting it back to json or xml.

You will have to check every equipment vendor you have!

I would suggest creating an interface in code and implement one per device. Then the code which converts to json / xml and / or saves to database does not need to be aware of the specific device it's being used.